# Element does not float to the left as told

Tags: html, css

I have a little CSS problem. This occurs in IE, FF and Chrome. However on the iPhone Safari browser, it looks fine. The problem is that the second 'block' span tag (`id="myDiv"`) does not float to the left as the first block span tag does, it has a padding to the left of some sort, which I never applied. How can I remove that padding to the left of the `id="myDiv"` span tag?

```
<head>
 <style>
    .plansHeader{
      font-weight:bold;color:rgb(73,102,145);font-size:12pt;margin-bottom:6px;line-  
      height:14pt;
     }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span style="display: block">
    <img src="http://m.v4m.mobi/uni/thumbs/arrow.png" border="none" style="vertical-align: middle; float: left;"/>
    <span id="plansHeader">e-phone to e-phone calls: R0.40 p/m</span> 
  </span>
  <span id="myDiv" style="display: block">
    <img src="http://m.v4m.mobi/uni/thumbs/arrow.png" border="none" style="vertical-align: middle; float: left;" />
    <span class="plansHeader">0 minutes call time included(to Any mobile/landline)</span>
  </span>           
</body>
```

Thanks You

Comment: some sidenotes: 1) try to avoid inline-css and use a stylesheet for that. 2) Why are you abusing those span-tags? Use `<div>`s which are proper block-elements.

Comment: good point, but I ommited the <li> tags this all is nested in...can I still use divs inside other non-block elements such as list tags?

Comment: It makes no difference if you take a `div` or a `span` with `display:block;` - you have to declare `display:block;` on your `li` too in both cases because the block'ed span is a block-level element too.

Comment: @DexterSchneider - The [content model for LI elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) is `flow content (%flow;)` which includes DIV elements. That's all that matters. CSS can never change the content model of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this after your span :

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

It's should look like this:

```
<span style="display: block">
   <img src="http://m.v4m.mobi/uni/thumbs/arrow.png" border="none" style="vertical-align: middle; float: left;"/>
   <span id="plansHeader">e-phone to e-phone calls: R0.40 p/m</span> 
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>

<span id="myDiv" style="display: block">
  <img src="http://m.v4m.mobi/uni/thumbs/arrow.png" border="none" style="vertical-align: middle; float: left;" />
  <span class="plansHeader">0 minutes call time included(to Any mobile/landline)</span>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>
```

and remeber: **Always clear floats!**

Comment: thank you, it works. One other problem though, when the text in the  span tags below the images gets shifted to a next line, it also floats to the left, right below the image. I want it to align with the top part of the text(I do not want any text below the image).I tried text-justify but it dies not work.

Comment: This is the way how it should be wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/BaR7A/ :) Simplicity is everything!

Comment: thanks, got it, i just set the text span tags to display: table-cell;

Answer (score 2):

It does, but your image is slightly taller than the line on which the image appears, so the second line is floating against the margin of the image.

You need to clear floats (either by adding a div between lines with style for `clear: both` or setting CSS on the second block to clear the float) to prevent this from happening.  You could also just set the first line to `line-height: 21px`, the height of your image (which I'd recommend you do anyway), and that'll fix it, but ultimately you'll want to clear the floats to be safe.